# Why do titles containing ".." remove these dots

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, title

An example would be [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/147697/72471). I had to exchange the original double dot `..` in the title with `..` in the question title.

Why does SE remove the double dots in a question title?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It strips dots [from the end of the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187234/145982) because it thinks you're ending the question in a period or ellipses. It also converts trailing exclamation points to question marks, as part of an attempt to keep titles consistent.

Comment: I think before posting here another question about unix.stackexchange, I'll have a look at meta.stackexchange.com